# Why does it draw so slow?

Tags: java, performance, animation, draw

I'm trying to develop a simple 2D game and for the animating, I'm using Timer and TimerTask.

But it draws so slow only when I call repaint for Background image which is 24000 X 1600 size and 30MB png file. And it was fine when I called other repaints.

Is it because I draw too big image?

I have tried with 24000 X 1600, 130KB png file but it still has drawn so slow.. What is the problem??

Ah, and also, I'm trying to draw it on the JPanel which is within Container.

Here's my code

```
public void setIcon() {
    try {
        imgBackground = ImageIO.read(new File("./Images/Background/Background_1.png"));
        imgBackground = convertToARGB(imgBackground);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

public static BufferedImage convertToARGB(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    return newImage;
}

public void drawBackground() {
    if (backgroundX >= -25900) {
        buffg.drawImage(imgBackground, backgroundX, 0, null);
        if (gameState) {
            if (keyRight) {
                backgroundX -= 3;
            } else {
                backgroundX -= 2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (background2X >= -25900) {
        buffg.drawImage(imgBackground, background2X, 0, null);
        if (gameState) {
            if (keyRight) {
                background2X -= 3;
            } else {
                background2X -= 2;
            }
        }
    }
    if ((backgroundX <= -22000) && (background2X <= -25900))
        background2X = fWidth;
    if ((background2X <= -22000) && (backgroundX <= -25900))
        backgroundX = fWidth;
}

public void start(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 50, 10);
}

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        playerMoveProcess();
        getContentPane().repaint();
        getContentPane().revalidate();
    }
};
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is huuuge. Let's say that drawing one pixel takes 1 nanosecond. Then drawing the whole image takes 38.4 milliseconds.

You should really ensure that not the whole image is drawn, but restrict the drawing to those parts that actually changed.

When I first saw the 24000 I thought *it's a typo*. It must be a typo. No one produces images this large and expects them to be processed efficiently.

Comment: Hahahah.... that wasn't typo. I actually have been trying with 24000 X 1600 size. But I think just my coding is problematic, because I tried with 2400X1400 but it was also drawn very slow.